# How to do a projection on Freemarker sequences to extract a property?

Tags: freemarker

Let's say I have some object `container` in a freemarker variable and `container.content` gives me a sequence of objects (I will call them "things") with names and a `String getName()` accessor. I would like to produce a comma-separated list of the names from the `container.content` sequence.

If I already had a sequence of names instead of a sequence of things with names, I could simply do `names?join(", ")`. Is there something concise to extract the `.name`-s from `container.content` and join them afterwards? More generally, I am looking for a functional programming map (collect, projection) operation, but did not find one in the docs.

What I have tried for now:

Currently, I have `<#list container.content as x>${x.name}<#if x?has_next>, </#if></#list>` to reproduce that map-then-join operation, but I find that rather verbose and it looks like a smell to me to have basically reimplemented `join`.

Previously I had `container.content?join(", ")` and I got `"Thing[name=A, otherStuff=...], Thing[name=B, otherStuff=...]"` instead of `"A, B"`, of course. I do not wish to modify that `Thing#toString` method to only return the name instead. I would like to keep that detailed representation for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create function which will extract key values from input sequence:

```
<#function map seq key>
    <#assign result = []>
    <#list seq as item>
        <#assign result = result + [item[key]]>
   </#list>
  <#return result>
</#function>
```

And then use it like that:

```
${map(container.content, "name")?join(", ")}
```

Comment: Thank you. How does this behave performance wise? I read somewhere else that one might want to avoid repetitive sequence concatenation.

Comment: AFAIK this is the only way to create a sequence/list in FreeMarker. If you want performance, then you should prepare that list in Java and pass it in model.